# Counting the number of child records in a one-to-many relationship with SQL only

Tags: sql, count, distinct, one-to-many

I have a database with two tables: `data` and `file`.

`file_id` is a foreign key from `data` to `file`. So, the relationship from `data` to `file` is n to one.

Is there a way with using SQL only to find out how many records of `data` refer to each record of `file`?

For example, I can find how many records of data are referring to file with id 13:

```
select count(*) from data where file_id = 13;
```

I want to know this for every file_id. I tried the following command to achive this, but it gives the count for all file_id records:

```
mysql> select distinct file_id, count(*) from data where file_id in (select id from file);
+---------+----------+
| file_id | count(*) |
+---------+----------+
|       9 |     3510 |
+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Distinct returns distinct values per row, not per some group. MySql allows for use of aggregate functions without a group by, which is totally misleading. In this case you got a random file_id and a count of all records - certainly something you did not intend to do.

To get group count (or any other aggregate function), use group by clause:

```
select file_id, count(*)
  from data
 group by file_id
```

Comment: How would you ad a `where` clause that interacted with the `count(*)`? E.g. select the count where the count is greater than 5?

Comment: @DogEatDog Add having clause after group by: `having count(*) > 5`.

Answer (score 5):

GROUP BY...

```
SELECT file_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM data
 GROUP BY file_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select file_id, count(*)
  from data
 group by file_id
```