# display a list of courses order by the number of comments of each course

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two classes : Course and Comment. 
I would like to display a list of courses ordered by the number of comments of each course. For example, the course that have the greatest number of comments should be the first on the list ....Someone please help me find an efficient query to do that. Thanks.

```
class Course(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True )
course_name =db.Column(db.String(120))
course_description = db.Column(db.Text)
course_comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref ='course', lazy ='dynamic')





class Comment(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True )
comment_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
comment = db.Column(db.Text)
course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.id'))
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that you want to do, in terms of SQL, is count the number of instances in a group and then order by that counting. This question gives some background: [Counting the number of child records in a one-to-many relationship with SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064194/counting-the-number-of-child-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-sql-only)

So in SQL I think you want to do is something like:

```
SELECT course_id, count(*) 
FROM comment 
GROUP BY course_id 
ORDER BY count(*);
```

This gives you the course id's from the comments table sorted by the number of comments. This answer shows us how to do this in sqlalchemy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086229/1216837

```
import desc
import func.count
import order_by

session.query(Comment.course_id,func.count(Comment.course_id)).\
    group_by(Comment.course_id).\
    order_by(desc(func.count(Comment.course_id))).\
    all()
```